# categorise text in column using keywords

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, machine-learning, pyspark

I have a table column, that contain description of the treatment done to resolve an issue, this text contian keywords.

In other list, I have the list of categories, with the different keywords that helps to identify it.

For example:

---

### Category             | keywords

AAAA                  | keyword1

AAAA                  | keyword2 and keyword3

AAAA                  | keyword3 and not keyword4

BBBB                  | keyword4

BBBB                  | keyword5 and keyword6

BBBB                  | keyword7

how can fill the category column in my previous table (that contain the description), using the keywords in it.

For example:

---

```
     Description                  |  category
```

---

this free text keyword1 is done       |   AAAA

---

free sample2 keyword4 keyword3        |   BBBB

---

the language I'm using is python,

I found a similar case, but using Excel:
https://exceljet.net/formula/categorize-text-with-keywords

kIND REGARDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by creating a list of tuples where the first element is the category and the second is a dictionary with list of keywords that should be included/excluded from the description. For example

```
keyword_tuple = [('AAAA', {'in': ['kwrd1'], 'out':[]}), 
                 ('AAAA', {'in': ['kwrd2', 'kwrd3'], 'out': []),
                 ('AAAA', {'in': ['kwrd3'], 'out': ['kwrd4']}), 
                 ('BBBB', {'in': ['kwrd4'], 'out': [])]
```

After you have initialized correctly your `keyword_tuple` you can loop through your descriptions list to determine to which category they belong. Let's store the results in a list of tuples called `result_tuple` where the first element is the description and the second the corresponding category.

```
result_tuple = []

for description in description_list:
    # Find categories that satisfy the include condition
    categories_in = [cat[0] for cat in keyword_tuple if all([kw in description for kw in cat[1]['in']])]
    # Find categories that satisfy the exclude condition
    categories_out = [cat[0] for cat in keyword_tuple if all([kw not in description for kw in cat[1]['out']])]

    # Find the categories that satisfy both 
    # If there are multiple categories satisfying the condition, you need to come with a decision rule
    categories = list(set(categories_in).intersection(categories_out))

    # Append to the result list (Takes the first that is satisfied)
    if len(categories) > 0:
        category = categories[0]
    else:
        category = 'NO CATEGORY'

    result_tuple.append(description, category)
```

Comment: when you said, the case of and not, has to be handled separatly, how ?

Comment: another thing, right now: I have a 2 columns xls table for the category, and keywords, how can I create a python list from this source ?

Comment: For your second question, you can save the xls file as csv and then import it in python using pandas. Then you can easily convert that to list. For the first, I will edit my answer.

Comment: category: AAAA
rule: KW1&KW2&NOTKW3
how can from such records, build the keyword tuple you mentionned ? i'm so sorry, i'm debutant in python

Comment: This is a different question and depends on the exact format of your rules. Schematically you can parse a single entry like `(category, {'in' : rule.split('&NOT')[0].split('&'), 'out': rule.split('&NOT')[1].split('&NOT')})`

Comment: my rules are writting in this format:
@KW1&KW2&NOTKW3 [KW1* AND KW2* NOT KW3 ] 

I want first to remove the part [xxxx], to remove the "@" at first, and then split my rule to the inclusion parts (for this case KW1, KW2), and the exlusion part (KW3)

Comment: `{'in': rule.split(' [')[0].split('&NOT')[0].split('&'), 'out': rule.split(' [')[0].split('&NOT')[1:]}` Hope that now your question is fully answered..

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's very helpful, just want to get something straight, so when you are parsing the row with this formula, is it just formating it in a dictionary format ? or converting it actually ?

Comment: Yes it actually creates a new `dict` with the rules parsed as two `lists`. One with words that must be included (`in` key) and one with words that must be excluded (`out` key). If you think it is solved, you can mark the answer by selecting the tick sign.

Comment: how can I loop over my records (category and rule), to get such a list of tuples, that you named keyword_tuple (I don't know how you can in a same loop do that, because, I tried the append function but it's working only on lists, not dictionary (for rule part) ?!

Comment: forget about the loop part, I succed to do it, but I'm still struggling to remove the character '@' from the beggining of my rules (it's not always present), some rules have it, others don't, I tried the following function, but it's not working:                                                              for l in range(1,df3.nrows):
    if '@' in df3.row_values(l)[1]:
  df3.row_values(l)[1] = df3.row_values(l)[1].replace('@', '')

Comment: you can add another `split` level in parsing.. 
`{'in': rule.split('@')[-1].split(' [')[0].split('&NOT')[0].split('&'), 'out': rule.split('@')[-1].split(' [')[0].split('&NOT')[1:]}`

Comment: and will it work even if some rules doesn't contain the '@' ?

Comment: It will.... try `'test'.split('@')[-1]` and `'@test'.split('@')[-1]` to validate yourself :)

Comment: yes, it's working super fine, thank you very much                            I have another type of rules, that I find very hard to implement with my categories, such as: @KW1&KW2[KW1* NEAR KW2*/A/C5],                                   the last digit "5" means that the category linked to this rule is given only if the distance between the keyword 1 and keywords is at max 5 (maximum 4 string between them), how can I implement that ?

Comment: well, this gets quite far from the original question and it worth an investigation by its own. I suggest that you raise a new question on how you can parse a rule of that form into a `dict` of type `{'in': [in_list], 'out': [out_list]}`

Comment: I'll do that, in the meantime, I have a question about your solution, as let's imagine that I have 2 categories, one with kw1 and second with kw1 and kw2, if my description contain kw1 and kw2, normally, I should get as a category output both categories, as technically they both match, and then I'll need to sort the choices by preference order (in this case, the category that contain the maximum keyword, will be ranked 1st and then the other one)